# codeigniter - how to call helper method only in default controller and method

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I created a **helper** for save `user_agent` in `db` that have a method `saveVisit();`

visit_helper :

```
  function saveVisit($visitable_type='',$visitable_id='')
  {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('user_agent');
    $ip = $CI->input->ip_address();

    $userId = $CI->session->userdata('userId');
    if (!isset($userId)) {
      $userId = 0;
    }
    if ($CI->agent->is_mobile()) {
      $mobile=$CI->agent->mobile();
    }else {
      $mobile=0;
    }
    $data = array(
      'ip'=>$ip,
      'visitable_id'=>$visitable_id,
      'visitable_type'=>$visitable_type,
      'user_id'=>$userId,
      'created_at'=>dbtime(),
      'browser'=>$CI->agent->browser(),
      'version'=>$CI->agent->version(),
      'platform'=>$CI->agent->platform(),
      'mobile'=>$mobile,
      'referral'=>$CI->agent->referrer(),
    );
    $CI->db->insert('visits',$data);
  }
```

When i call a method like `saveVisit();`that created in my **helper**, everything is ok and it called where i writed !

But when i call this method from `$route['default_controller'] = 'display/home';` this method will called from all of **methods** in all of my **controllers** !!!

I want to  call this method only home page not all **controllers/methods** !

This issue is for only my `$route['default_controller'] = 'display/home';`

code of my controller :

```
class Display extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
  {
        parent::__construct();
  }
    public function home()
    {
        // some codes here 
        saveVisit('home');
    }
}
```

I want `saveVisit();` called only in home page not others

**EDITED :**

I created a new function in **helper** to test and called in default **controller** , function is called once **BUT** runned **twice** !

test **method** code in helper :

```
 function test()
  {
      $CI =& get_instance();

      if ($CI->session->userdata('visit')!=null) {
        $plus = $CI->session->userdata('visit');
        $CI->session->set_userdata('visit',$plus+1);
        echo $CI->session->userdata('visit');
      }else {
        $CI->session->set_userdata('visit',1);
      }
```

And when i call `test();` inside default `Controller` result for every page refresh is (Other controllers was Normal) :

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
.
.
.
```

Why this happen ?

**EDIT 3 :**

When i call a **helper function** inside **default controller** it will run twice and run once from other **controllers** ! the problem is i didn't call **function** in other **controllers**

Comment: What's an example URL path of a different controller method that you have tested?

Comment: @codeafin any `controller` and `method` like `blog/index` `blog/one` `product/show` and ....

Comment: Does the new test() visit count still increase when you visit `product/show`?

Comment: @codeafin as you see in my question this problem is only for default controller not others ! No Not increased twice in `product/show` . in this path everything is normal

Comment: There is no reason for the function to be called on other controllers. With regards to double counting on first page it can either be user error or you are simply running ajax calls to the page or whatever that is increasing the view count.

Comment: @Alex i didn't use `Ajax` and i have not any error ! its a simple `controller` and simple `helper` !

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.... It isn't normal for a function to be called when it isn't called... In this case the function should only be called once at home()

Comment: @Alex the `function` be called once but **runned** twice , that's problem

Comment: I understand but php doesn't work that way. Irregardless of ci.

Comment: @Alex have a solution ?  i edited my question .can be about .htaccess file ?

Comment: Php function executing twice has nothing to do with htacess

Comment: @Alex if htaccess cause a extra redirect

Comment: @samnikzad can you specify where you have called the `test()` function, it seems it may be called twice, any of precontorller or hooks, did you happen to check that?

Comment: @MalayM i called this method inside default controller , not different witch method ! in `Display/home` , `Display/index` , `Display/test` and ...

Comment: i suggest doing a code-wide `find` for `saveVisit()` to see where you might be calling it twice. perhaps you even called it in the helper file in which it resides.

Comment: @Alex nothing duplicated or calling twice by me ! its a `codeigniter` problem  . i solved this problem by removing `404` page in `config` file !!!

Comment: It's not a codeigniter problem. Tens of thousands of websites run on ci, functions running twice for no apparent reason hasn't been documented. It's **user error**, but we don't have enough info to determine what the cause was.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling  `test()` function to each of the function in **`Display`** class, call it inside `__construct()`

```
<?php

class Display extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        test();
    }

    public function home(){
        // some codes here 
        saveVisit('home');

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't called `test()` in each method ! I mean, `test()` run twice ~ and caused duplicated raw in `db` . No matter where to call `test()`